# Applying a specified rule to build an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider array `a` whose columns hold random values taken from 1, 2, 3:

```
a = np.array([[2, 3, 1, 3],
              [3, 2, 1, 3],
              [1, 1, 1, 2],
              [1, 3, 2, 3],
              [3, 3, 1, 3],
              [2, 1, 3, 2]])
```

Now, consider array `b` whose first 2 columns hold the 9 possible pairs of values taken from 1, 2, 3  (the order of the pair elements is important).  The 3rd column of `b` associates a non-negative integer with each pairing.

```
b = np.array([[1, 1, 6],
              [1, 2, 0],
              [1, 3, 9],
              [2, 1, 6],
              [2, 2, 0],
              [2, 3, 4],
              [3, 1, 1],
              [3, 2, 0],
              [3, 3, 8]])
```

I need help with code that produces array `c` where vertically adjacent elements in `a` are replaced with matching values from the 3rd column of `b`.
For example, the first column of 'a' moves down from 2 to 3 to 1 to 1 to 3 to 2.   So, the first column of `c` would hold values  4, 1, 6, 9, 0.  The same idea applies to every column of `a`.   We see that pair order is important (moving from 3 to 1 produces value 1, while moving from 1 to 3 produces value 9.

The output of this small example would be:

```
c = np.array([[4, 0, 6, 8],
              [1, 6, 6, 0],
              [6, 9, 0, 4],
              [9, 8, 6, 8],
              [0, 1, 9, 0]])
```

Because this code will be executed a vast number of times, I'm hoping there is a speedy vectorized solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `b` contains all the pairs you can efficiently reshape it to square form, indexed by its row/col number, then form the pairs of indices with [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) and index the square intermediate:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

s = np.full((b[:, 0].max()+1, b[:, 1].max()+1), -1)
s[b[:, 0], b[:, 1]] = b[:, 2]

v = swv(a, 2, axis=0)
out = s[v[..., 0], v[..., 1]]
```

Variant with `0` based indexing (produces a slightly more packed intermediate):

```
s = np.full((b[:, 0].max(), b[:, 1].max()), -1)
s[b[:, 0]-1, b[:, 1]-1] = b[:, 2]

v = swv(a, 2, axis=0)-1
out = s[v[..., 0], v[..., 1]]
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 0, 6, 8],
       [1, 6, 6, 0],
       [6, 9, 0, 4],
       [9, 8, 6, 8],
       [0, 1, 9, 0]])
```

Intermediate `s`:

```
array([[-1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1,  6,  0,  9],
       [-1,  6,  0,  4],
       [-1,  1,  0,  8]])

# variant
array([[6, 0, 9],
       [6, 0, 4],
       [1, 0, 8]])
```

---

If you had arbitrary values making it difficult to generate a dense square intermediate, you could use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)'s [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv
import pandas as pd

out = (pd.DataFrame(swv(a, 2, axis=0).reshape(-1, 2))
         .merge(pd.DataFrame(b), how='left')
         [2].to_numpy()
         .reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
       )
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 0, 6, 8],
       [1, 6, 6, 0],
       [6, 9, 0, 4],
       [9, 8, 6, 8],
       [0, 1, 9, 0]])
```

##### timings

With a dense input (i.e. the indices are in the form 0->n (or 1->n) without missing indices), a square NxN `a` with `1->N` indices (N=1000):

```
# numpy
16.5 ms ± 941 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# pandas
173 ms ± 17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

With a sparse input (indices are `N` values selected among a larger set ; here 1000 values out of 50_000 possibilities ; ~2% density ; ~0.04% density in square form):

```
# numpy
5.04 s ± 2.5 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# pandas
192 ms ± 13.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Appreciate the timings vs density comments - very insightful

Comment: Given `b` is sorted, why not just `s = b[:,2].reshape(3,3)` for the 0-based indexing variant?

Comment: @Nick because I didn't want to make the assumption that the data is sorted. But that's true, you can use this shortcut if it is ;)